# For range loop variable passing by reference to go routine causes memory leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks

Code for reproducing the problem

go version go1.19 darwin/amd64

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    M []byte
}

var lkMap sync.Mutex
var tMap map[string]*TestStruct

const objectCount = 1024 * 100

func main() {

    tMap = make(map[string]*TestStruct)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(objectCount)
    func1(wg)
    wg.Add(objectCount)
    func2(wg)

    wg.Wait()
    runtime.GC()
    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil))
}

//go:noinline
func func1(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    ts := []*TestStruct{}
    for i := 0; i < objectCount; i++ {
        t := &TestStruct{}
        ts = append(ts, t)
        lkMap.Lock()
        tMap[strconv.Itoa(i)] = t
        lkMap.Unlock()
    }

    for i, t := range ts {
        go func(t *TestStruct, idx int) {
            t.M = bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(32)}, 1024)

            lkMap.Lock()
            delete(tMap, strconv.Itoa(idx))
            lkMap.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }(t, i) //pass by reference
    }
}

//go:noinline
func func2(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    ts := []*TestStruct{}
    for i := 0; i < objectCount; i++ {
        t := &TestStruct{}
        ts = append(ts, t)

        lkMap.Lock()
        tMap[strconv.Itoa(i+objectCount)] = t
        lkMap.Unlock()
    }
    for i, t := range ts {
        tmp := t //capture here
        idx := i
        go func() {
            tmp.M = bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(32)}, 1024)

            lkMap.Lock()
            delete(tMap, strconv.Itoa(idx+objectCount))
            lkMap.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
}
```

Run this program and using pprof to fetch the heap using the command line:

```bash
go tool pprof http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap
```

will produce the diagram like this:
[image: pprof1]

As I can see the func1 is clearly leaking. The only difference between func1 and func2 is that func2 uses a local variable to capture the loop variable.

However, if I remove the global map both functions are fine, no one is leaking.

So is there something to do with the global map manipulation?

Thank you for any input

Edit:
Thanks @nipuna for pointing out that changing the order of func1 and func2 in main function will make func2 show in the report. However func1 is still hoarding the most memory which is 51.32% as func2 is retaining 19.33%
[image: pprof2]

Comment: I have put the same functions as `func1` and `func2` and tested and still `func1` shows red in the new diagram. And then I changed the order of the function call in the `main()` and then `func2` shows in the diagram as red.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this. You are right about the result, but even after changing the order func1 still retains the most of the memory which is 53.77% comparing to func2 which is 16.89%. see the picture below:

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that profiler diagrams are any strong witnesses in the memory leak trial.

Go runtime can tell about its memory allocation much more than profiler. Try [`runtime.ReadMemStats`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#ReadMemStats) to output heap readings.

Here is my experiment: https://go.dev/play/p/279du2yB3BZ

```
func printAllocInfo(message string) {
    var memStats runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&memStats)
    fmt.Println(message,
        "Heap Alloc:", memStats.HeapAlloc,
        "Heap objects:", memStats.HeapObjects)
}

func main() {

    tMap = make(map[string]*TestStruct)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(objectCount)
        printAllocInfo("Before func2:")
        func2(wg)
        wg.Wait()
        runtime.GC()
        printAllocInfo("After func2: ")
    }
    println("----------------------------")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(objectCount)
        printAllocInfo("Before func1:")
        func1(wg)
        wg.Wait()
        runtime.GC()
        printAllocInfo("After func1: ")
    }
    println("----------------------------")
    runtime.GC()
    printAllocInfo("after GC: ")
    println("----------------------------")
}
```

The output is

```
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 260880 Heap objects: 1224
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 1317904 Heap objects: 2749
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 1319288 Heap objects: 2757
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 1576656 Heap objects: 3425
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 1578040 Heap objects: 3433
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 1858408 Heap objects: 4197
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 1859792 Heap objects: 4205
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2210760 Heap objects: 4909
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2212144 Heap objects: 4917
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2213200 Heap objects: 4799
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2214584 Heap objects: 4807
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2247480 Heap objects: 5045
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2248864 Heap objects: 5053
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2298840 Heap objects: 5158
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2300224 Heap objects: 5166
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2297144 Heap objects: 5047
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2298528 Heap objects: 5055
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2316712 Heap objects: 5154
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2318096 Heap objects: 5162
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 3083256 Heap objects: 7208
----------------------------
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3084640 Heap objects: 7216
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3075816 Heap objects: 7057
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3077200 Heap objects: 7065
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3102896 Heap objects: 7270
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3104280 Heap objects: 7278
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3127728 Heap objects: 7461
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3129112 Heap objects: 7469
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3128352 Heap objects: 7401
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3129736 Heap objects: 7409
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3121152 Heap objects: 7263
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3122536 Heap objects: 7271
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3167872 Heap objects: 7703
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3169256 Heap objects: 7711
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3163120 Heap objects: 7595
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3164504 Heap objects: 7603
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3157376 Heap objects: 7470
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3158760 Heap objects: 7478
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3160496 Heap objects: 7450
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 3161880 Heap objects: 7458
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 3221024 Heap objects: 7754
----------------------------
after GC:  Heap Alloc: 3222200 Heap objects: 7750
----------------------------
```

Looks like you are right - with every iteration the number of object in the heap is constantly growing.

But what if we swap `func1` and `func2`? Let's call `func2` before `func1`: https://go.dev/play/p/ABFq1O11bIl

```
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 261456 Heap objects: 1227
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 1330584 Heap objects: 2529
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 1331968 Heap objects: 2537
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 1739280 Heap objects: 3755
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 1740664 Heap objects: 3763
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2251824 Heap objects: 5017
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2253208 Heap objects: 5025
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2244400 Heap objects: 4802
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2245784 Heap objects: 4810
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2287816 Heap objects: 5135
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2289200 Heap objects: 5143
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2726136 Heap objects: 6375
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2727520 Heap objects: 6383
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2834520 Heap objects: 6276
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2835904 Heap objects: 6284
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2855496 Heap objects: 6393
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2856880 Heap objects: 6401
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2873064 Heap objects: 6478
Before func2: Heap Alloc: 2874448 Heap objects: 6486
After func2:  Heap Alloc: 2923560 Heap objects: 6913
----------------------------
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2924944 Heap objects: 6921
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2933416 Heap objects: 6934
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2934800 Heap objects: 6942
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2916520 Heap objects: 6676
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2917904 Heap objects: 6684
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2941816 Heap objects: 6864
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2943200 Heap objects: 6872
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2968184 Heap objects: 7078
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2969568 Heap objects: 7086
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2955056 Heap objects: 6885
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2956440 Heap objects: 6893
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2961056 Heap objects: 6893
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2962440 Heap objects: 6901
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 2967680 Heap objects: 6903
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 2969064 Heap objects: 6911
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 3005856 Heap objects: 7266
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 3007240 Heap objects: 7274
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 3033696 Heap objects: 7514
Before func1: Heap Alloc: 3035080 Heap objects: 7522
After func1:  Heap Alloc: 3028432 Heap objects: 7423
----------------------------
after GC:  Heap Alloc: 3029608 Heap objects: 7419
----------------------------
```

Heap of `func2` grows almost as fast as with `func1`, and `func1` being in the second place behaves exactly like `func2` - adds just 500 objects to the heap.

From these two examples I can't agree that *`func1` is leaking while `func2` is not*. I'd say, they are leaking to the same degree.

Comment: Much appreciated for your detailed break down. I didn't think of using runtime.ReadMemStats, that's a brilliant approach! Since the func2 is leaking just as func1, this makes me worry again. Because I just switch to func2 way on my production server :). Do you know the root reason for this leaking or some way to fix this problem?

Comment: @davyzhang unfortunately I'm not an expert in the Go runtime internals. Still I don't think it is really a memory leak.

Comment: No worries, Thank you again. you've helped me enough. I believe it is a real leaking problem. func1 is the first attempt I put on the production server. Within 24 hours memory was consumed significantly, after switching to func2 style, this problem has gone. It took me many hours to narrow the problem and reproduce the similar result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer from golang-nuts group, quote here:

> I don't think it's related with for-range loops, both should "leak"
> the same, I bet that's tMap, currently in Go maps do not shrink, even
> if you delete keys. One way to reduce memory usage of a long-living
> map is to at some threshold copy over all its elements into a new map,
> and set the old to map to this copy, then the old map, if not
> referenced elsewhere, will eventually be gc'ed and cleaned up.

The root cause is the long-lived map

I also found the issue here:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20135